# Can a class library developed in .net core 2.2 be referenced by an app written in .net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm working on a .net core 3.0 API and would need to reference class libraries that were developed using .net core 2.2. Will there be compatibility problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference .net core 2.2 libraries from a .net core 3.0 project, but not the other way around.

Also, [2.2 is no longer supported](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) so consider upgrading